# I want to do a scale animation in UIImageview, but I am getting an unexpected behaviour

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to do a scale animation with `UIImageview`, but when using this animation block the image view shifts a little right before animation. The code I used:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:(void (^)(void)) ^{

                 imgLogoImage.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.03, 1.03);

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     imgLogoImage.transform=CGAffineTransformIdentity;

                 }];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to scale UIImageView properly with UIView animateWithDuration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081076/how-to-scale-uiimageview-properly-with-uiview-animatewithduration)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is caused by your scale factor being too small, especially when the size scaled is relatively small for a relative long time(1 second).